# modal form (pop up window contains server controls)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, ajax

i wanna to do the following: but i donot how to do this in the correct way..

i have specific form has some buttons.. i wanna when click on a button a modal form appears,and this new form contains server controls and events fired when happening on this form how to handle this case like the dialog form in the Windows application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on telerik controls :
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx